# How to pull items from reference array based on condition in array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working in creating a todo list and one of the action I want users to do is delete all completed todos in one click. I have my models here, and the code I have, I have been reading trying to figure it out, but can't find it anywhere. Thanks in advance.

User Model

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  todos: [{
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Todo'
  }]
});
```

Todo model:

```
const TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
});
```

This is what I have now. I get a "Cast to ObjectId failed for value true at path todos.

```
router.delete('/delete/completed', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userTodos = await User.update(
      {'_id':req.user.id},
      { $pull: {  'todos': { 'completed': true } } },
      { multi: true }
    );

    if (!userTodos) {
      return res.status(400).send('Server error');
    }

    return res.json({ userTodos });
    //return res.json({msg: 'All completed removed'})
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Something went wrong, try again' });
  }
});
```

Comment: Your `User.todos` collection contains a list of `ObjectId's`, but you are trying to check it against a `Boolean` condition.

Comment: How would I be able to pull all the completed todos at once? I really don't know how to do that. I am able to delete one by id, can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

If you are (as it seems from your code) using mongoose, you could use mongoose's [populate feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate):

```
const userTodos = await User.find(
  {'_id':req.user.id}).populate('todos', {
    match: {completed: true}
  });
```

please note, however, that you'll need to delete both the documents in the todos collection, AND the todo reference in the user's todos array. You may consider to remove one side of the reference, see the pros and cons of two-way referencing [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)